# how to translate formatted text in react native?

Tags: react-native, internationalization

I use react-native-i18n for translating my app. I have a "formatted" text, like:

```
<Text>Normal text <Text bold>this is bold</Text> back to normal</Text>
```

Is it possible to make this text translatable in 1 or 2 strings instead of 3?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally, I've switched to [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/). It has a pretty decent react-native support, and seems to be much more elaborate than react-native-i18n is.

Comment: You did not explained how you finally did it through; I'm facing the same problem and I will be happy if you could elaborate your solution even using a different library

Answer (score 3):

You could, theoretically, have the translated text look something like markdown, e.g.

```
Normal text **bold text** back to normal
```

And then use some function to create the text elements, and use them in your code instead.

```
function textElements(text){
    return text.split('**').map((str, i) => 
        i % 2 == 0 ? 
            <Text key={key}>{str}</Text> : 
            <Text bold key={key}>{str}</Text bold>;
}
```

Whether this makes up code that is easier or harder to read, well, I suppose it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Its helped, indeed